# How to export agent population data into excel in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I want to take a time snapshot of agent population within system with all the parameter. Is there a way to export this data into excel or csv. Basically I want to validate few calculations manually.

Comment: Hey, please always first consult the AnyLogic help, there is a ton of info and also example models on this: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/export-excel.html#exporting-data-to-ms-excel-workbook :)

Comment: I tried using log functionality but it takes only the initial parameter value. I am changing agent parameter based on the flow condition.

Comment: Then add more details to what exactly you want to achieve and what you have tried. Some guidance: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution, drag the text file object from the connectivity pallet to your model. Change it to write, create a new text file and link it to the file you created.

Then have some button, event or function and you simply add the following type of code:

```
for (MyAgent myAgent:myAgentPopulation) {
    file.println(
        myAgent.name + "\t" +
        myAgent.age + "\t"
        myAgent.gender + "\t"
        myAgent.work + "\t"
    );
}
```

the `"\t"` is for creating a tab separated file, you can use `"`"` for comma separated CSV